# How to make the date reflect on jetstream x-jet-input?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8 jetstream, there is a component x-jet-input, which will display the input based on the type.

x-jet-input code:

```xml
@props(['disabled' => false])

<input {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }} {!! $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-input rounded-md shadow-sm']) !!}>
```

I added these code in update-profile-information-form.blade.php to let user update their date of birth in case they put it wrongly when register. But the date picker does not show the existing date in the date picker.

```xml
<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label for="date_of_birth" value="Date of Birth" />
    <x-jet-input id="date_of_birth" type="date" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.date_of_birth" />
    <x-jet-input-error for="date_of_birth" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

How can I do this using x-jet-input?

[date does not show in date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvkmA.png)

Comment: Is `date_of_birth` present when you do `dd(Auth::user()->withoutRelations()->toArray())`? If so, what is its format?

Comment: It shows this format. "date_of_birth" => "2020-12-15 00:00:00"

Comment: It's a formatting problem then. the date input expects a `Y-m-d` format. You can add it to your `$casts` property in the `User` model

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. Looks like there are lot more of Laravel I need to learn! :)

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comment, The problem is the date input expects the value as `2020-12-15`.

To solve this, just add the following to your `$casts` in the `User` model

```php
protected $casts = [
    'date_of_birth' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check does working a datepicker on a simple element input, this will allow you to exclude the category of errors related to JS (I suspect that the case is in JS)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).